# Display more than one icon on a list item

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, icons

How can I place more than one icon on a list item?

In particular I'd like to place them on the right side of the list item to the left of the arrow.

[image]

I've tried placing 2 images within the `<a>` tag of the list item and positioning them with css but it didn't work as hoped.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/16.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none icon1">
        <img src="images/16.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none icon2">
        Test
    </a>
</li>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9agagjf5/) with my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some absolute positioning CSS and wrapper DIVs like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        Test
        <div class="rightImages right1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/22/22/technics/1/" />
        </div> 
        <div class="rightImages right2">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/22/22/technics/2/" />                       
        </div> 
    </a>
</li>
```

Then the CSS is

```
.rightImages {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.right1 {
    right: 58px;
}
.right2 {
    right: 86px;
}
.rightImages img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0;
}
```

The extra wrapper DIV helps with the vertical centering. Depending on your actual image sizes, you will need to tweak the right1 and right2 classes.

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9agagjf5/3/)**